# How to setup VPN using an .ovpn file?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, system-settings

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 for about 3 days now and so far it runs smoothly. I now need to install a VPN for my work, and I got the following files from the sysadmin:

- ca.crt
- VPNConfig.ovpn

I first ran `sudo apt install openvpn`. After that I wanted to install it using the GUI. So I went to the settings app and under "Network" I tried adding a new VPN. It gives the option to "Import from a file". So I selected the `VPNConfig.ovpn` file, but it says it can't import the file. I also tried importing the `ca.crt` file and importing the zip in which the two files came, but that didn't work either.

Could anybody help me out as to how I can make this VPN work?

Comment: All you have to run is `openvpn --config openvpn_profile_here`

Comment: OP states that they want to use the GUI

Comment: I found that one can import a `*.ovpn` file into the _GUI_ using `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file /path/to/foo.ovpn`.  Couldn't post an answer here, but see my [answer to 'How to setup OpenVPN Client'](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071042/452725) for more details.

Comment: Totally disagree that this is a duplicate - a lot have changed since 1404.Especially in the GUI!

Comment: If the GUI has changed, post an updated answer on the dupe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to install a few packages first with:

```
sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

then, restart network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and try again. If it doesn't work, then try logging out and back in, if not, then try rebooting.

Comment: Thanks! You made my day! Just a question: why is pptp supported by default, but does openvpn support need to be installed seperately?

Comment: I don't know. I guess the Ubuntu team decided that not enough people use it to make it worth being part of the standard OS.

Comment: For a long time it didn't work for me, even though it worked from the command line. Finally I disabled ipv6 in the GUI and then it worked. Maybe this also helps other people.

Comment: Important: I probably had the same issue as @kramer65, then after revisiting https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007929314-Set-Up-OpenVPN-on-Linux-Ubuntu-via-Network-Manager I've learned that if you don't disable IPv6 on your physical device, it will still leak IPv6 connections outside of the VPN connection. I wonder how many people think they're protected by their VPNs while in fact they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble importing .ovpn files as well.  It seems to work on some machines and not others.  However, it is not difficult to set up the connection using Network Manager.  Many critical settings are only accessed after you click on the "Advanced" button, perhaps you didn't look there.

```
Example
 <general tab>
  Tick "all users may connect to this network"
 <VPN tab>
  Set connection name
  Set server name in Gateway box
  Set type to Certificates (TLS)
  Import user certificate XXX.crt
  Import ca certificate YYY.crt
  Import private key ZZZ.key
  <advanced button> 
   Tick use LZO data compression
   Tick set virtual device type, TUN name tun
```

If you have other settings look through the tabs to find them.