# VPN "connecting" but nothing loading

Tags: vpn, openvpn, raspberrypi

I followed a [recent post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460871/how-to-setup-openvpn-client) from this site on how to setup an openVPN client on an Ubuntu machine. I have a PiHole and an openVPN server running on a RaspberryPi. I did

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

I generated an openvpn client file on my Raspberry Pi and copied it over to my linux laptop via SSH. I then set-up in Network options. I went to VPN, clicked +, double clicked "import from file", navigated to the client's .ovpn file, double clicked "device.ovpn". It then jumped to the VPN set-up with all the fields autocompleted.

When I click VPN then connect, I get a padlock icon in the top right and the wired network icon.

[image]

This suggests that it's connected, but all website requests timeout. As soon as I turn off the VPN, all website requests work instantly. I know that the RPi, openVPN and PiHole are working because I have used them all together on my Windows laptop and my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you mention is not complete, it looks like there is no proper forwarding setup.

I suggest [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) DigitalOcean tutorial on OpenVPN setup. It is very detailed and works.