# Connecting to an OpenVPN Server

Tags: openvpn

I'm still very new to understanding all this VPN / Server stuff so please bear in mind when helping.

I am trying to connect to an OpenVPN Server set up by my client.
I am wondering how to do I connect as a client to this server via the Ubuntu terminal?
All they have provided to me is the key and the WAN and LAN of their network.

Thank you.

Comment: In a terminal, type in `ssh username@host` where `username` should have been given to you (perhaps equal to your local user name), and `host` is either a host name that your computer can `ping` to, or an IP address. You should also have been given a password on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would need to install the OpenVPN client. After that,

If you got an *.ovpn file from your vendor, then you can refer to this thread to get a quick start:
[How to setup OpenVPN Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460871/how-to-setup-openvpn-client)

Otherwise, you would need to refer to "Step 8 — Creating the Client Configuration Infrastructure" as documented in this link:
[How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. It's a strange one as we have only been given a key. No opvn file or the certificates that are needed if we have to create it manually. Do you think it might not be a openvpn protocol could it be IPSec?

Comment: Are you connecting via SSH or OpenVPN? Perhaps the best answer is from you client, they should inform you how they want you to access the server, shouldn't them?